# head request returns different content-type

Tags: python-requests, http-headers

I have an object, that should be checked if it is image or not.

For this purpose i use `requests.head(url)`

When i do it from my computer, i get header `"Content-Type"=='image/jpeg'`
When i do it from server (same url, same request) i get header `"Content-Type"=='text/html'`. Url is the same!

Problem link is https://storage.concert.ua/Jvv/5/rC/5ca77edf91258/129e.jpg 
Please explain me what is up with different headers i receive from the same url, when i run the request at the same time, but from different physical location ?

I tried to add `User-Agent` header and `Accept : '*/*'` - this changed nothing

Comment: You are being served a [Cloudflare anti-ddos checking page](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/154975/what-is-the-website-checking-about-my-browser-to-protect-the-website-from-a-ddos).

Comment: but i didn't do too many requests to do a ddos

Comment: That doesn't matter, that URL is hosted via Cloudflare and they are protecting it from the possibility of a DDOS.